# Finding Thevenin Resistance Amp Op

Tags: circuit-analysis, operational-amplifier

[image]

Hello folks,

I've got some douts about how can finding the \$R_{th}\$ seen between \$V_{out}\$:

**A**: *is a amplifier gain*

The possible answer are:

A) \$ R_{th} = (A.R_s)\$
B) \$ R_{th} = (R_s + A)\$
C) \$ R_{th} = \frac{1}{R_s + A}\$
 
**D)** \$ R_{th} = (1+A).R_s\$
E) \$ R_{th} = (R_s + R_L).A\$

**The correct answer is D**.

My attempt:

Seems \$V_i\$ is a short circuit and the inputs amplifier are HiZ the \$R_{th}\$ will be:

[image]

\$ R_{th} = R_s + R(amplifier)\$

\$ R(\text{amplifier}) = 1V/I_N\$

\$I_N = A.1/(R_s+R_L) = A/(R_s+R_L)\$

\$R_{th} = R_s + (R_s+R_L)/2 = R_s(A+1) + R_L\$

Comment: To make the question more clear, make it clear that A to E are the given answers and that you **think** D is correct.

Comment: I've already fixed it.

Comment: I believe the controlling pins of the voltage controlled source should be connected to the **-** and ground terminal instead of a 1V voltage source. I also have a hunch that \$R_L\$ is supposed to be left out and replaced by a current source.

Comment: There's a comment which told that your opamp is something less than an ideal one.  Me and surely many others also are not that competent psychic mind readers, so you should define that in question, if that's true.

Comment: This is a ideal ampop but its gain is A not infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach when trying to find the Thevenin equivalent looking into a certain node or between two nodes (as in this case), is to place an ideal current source, say \$I_T\$ in parallel with the node(s) of interest and then finding the ratio of the voltage created by this current source \$V_T\$ and such current. $$R_T = \dfrac{V_T}{I_T}$$ 
Now back to your current circuit, you've followed the steps correctly by replacing \$V_{IN}\$ with it's equivalent short circuit but your circuit diagram is not completely correct. Assuming an ideal OpAmp, the corrected schematic including the sneaky \$I_T\$ is as follows

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f828db.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now the goal is to find $$\dfrac{V_T}{I_T}$$
  1. \$V_T = -A\cdot V_x - V_x\$ (difference between output and negative input terminal of the OpAmp)
  Thus $$V_T = -V_x(1 + A)$$
  2.\$V_x = -I_T\cdot R_s\$ (\$I_T\$ is an ideal current source so it forces the current in the whole circuit to be \$I_T\$)

Plugging 2 into 1
  $$V_T = I_T\cdot R_s(1 + A)$$
Dividing both sides by \$I_T\$ yields:
$$\dfrac{V_T}{I_T} = R_T = R_s(1 + A)$$

You can obtain the same results by placing a Voltage source \$V_T\$ in series with the element and finding the current \$I_T\$.

Comment: nicely done. I haven't figure out the plant a current source into the RL`s nodes. Thank you.

Comment: @miguel747 To apply Thevenin's theorem, you need to remove the component concerned with the nodes you're trying to get the equivalent resistance at. In this case `RL`. There's a good summary [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/dccircuits/dcp_7.html).

Answer (score 0):

That opamp circuit is normally an inverting amplifier with voltage gain Av=-RL/Rs. Normally the load is between the output of the opamp and GND. You have declared the output to be the terminals of RL. Without any load the voltage gain of course is still the same because the voltage in the minus input of the opamp must be 0V (=the virtual GND due the feedback)

If you insert a load in parallel with RL the output voltage drops because the gain decreases. We can check how this should be handled by considering the present circuit as a Thevenin source supplying the inserted load.

Let the load in parallel with RL be =Rx. We have now output voltage over Rx= Ux= -Vi(Rx par RL)/Rs where operator par means (Rx * RL)/(RL + Rx). The current through Rx =Ix = Ux/Rx.

By substituting all and mangling a while we have the current Ix = - Vi * (RL/Rs)/(Rx+RL)

That's voltage -Vi* (RL/Rs) divided by resistance Rx+RL. Thus the Thevenin equivalent seen by Rx is the following

- equivalent voltage source with voltage -Vi*(RL/Rs)
- equivalent series resistance Rth = RL.

None of your answer options is right if we assume the original problem is copied ok.

Comment: You are implicitly assuming that the op-amp gain is infinite. That is clearly not the intent in the question.

Comment: @EdgarBrown Not implicitly. There's an amplifier. That amplifier happens to be an inverting amplifier with an opamp which has surely enough gain to be considered as opamp because opamp symbol is used. The amplifier has gain -RL/Rs. Nothing in OP's text gives a reason to think that the opamp symbol is used for something less than a proper opamp.

Comment: Nothing? What about every single one of the possible answers,  the  feedback resistor being called RL, and the approach followed by miguel?

Comment: Anything can be copied wrong and totally wrong calculations or right calculations with wrong initial interpretations are possible as you just now claim. My writings are not better in that sense. The questioner surely tells to us if my answer is useless.

Comment: @EdgarBrown Now we know. I was wrong. The questioner wrote "This is a ideal ampop but its gain is A not infinity. – miguel747 4 hours ago"